# Retrieve Full name or Display name from LDAP server using AD and Apache shiro

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, shiro

I'm trying to authenticate a set of credentials against an LDAP server and I was able to authenticate them successfully. Now am trying to get the full name or the display name of the user logged-in into the server. Am unable to get the same. Being new to LDAP concepts, am unable to figure out a way to get the full display name of the user. Can some please help me how to get the full display name of the user logged in.

Below is the shiro.ini file am using:

```
[main]
activeDirectoryRealm = 
org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = adminusername
activeDirectoryRealm.systemPassword = adminpswd
activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = "OU=User Accounts,DC=dmn,DC=net"
activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldaps://localhost:389
```

My Java code is as below:

```
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.*;
import org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.apache.shiro.util.Factory;
public class ExampleActiveDirectory {


public static final String userName = "myusername";
public static final String password = "mypassword";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("N:\\workspace\\LdapAuthentication\\src\\auth.ini");
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("N:\\workspace\\LdapAuthentication\\src\\shiro.ini");
    SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager( securityManager );
    System.out.println( "userName is  : " +userName);
    System.out.println( "password is  : " +password);
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken( userName,password );
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    try
    {
        //currentUser.login( token ) ;
        securityManager.login(currentUser,token).isAuthenticated();
        System.out.println( "We've authenticated! :)" );
    }
    catch ( AuthenticationException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "We did not authenticate :(" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: currentUser.getPrincipal() will give you smth. like j.doe for the user john doe in case you search for this. Otherwise, provide example result you'd like to see.

Comment: I was kind of looking for a result like: If I enter the username as jdoe, the code needs to provide output like - john doe

Comment: Then I think you'd need to extend from Shiro's ActiveDirectoryRealm class and have a look at its method "getRoleNamesForUser". There is a search being executed over the AD using searchBase and searchFilter to retrieve the result. In this kind you could write your own method which uses the searchbase and filter and then look for attribute "name" instead of "memberOf". This attribute should give you the value you look for.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the info. 
link - http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/09/24/retrieve-basic-user-attributes-from-active-directory-using-ldap-in-java.html

Found a solution as below:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

import org.apache.shiro.web.tags.UserTag;

public class RetrieveUserAttributes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RetrieveUserAttributes retrieveUserAttributes = new RetrieveUserAttributes();
    retrieveUserAttributes.getUserBasicAttributes("username", retrieveUserAttributes.getLdapContext());
}

public LdapContext getLdapContext(){
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try{
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "adminusername");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "adminpswrd");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://localhost:389");
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");
    }catch(NamingException nex){
        System.out.println("LDAP Connection: FAILED");
        nex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}

UserTag getUserBasicAttributes(String username, LdapContext ctx) {
    UserTag user=null;
    try {

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attrIDs = { "distinguishedName",
                "sn",
                "givenname",
                "mail",
                "telephonenumber"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
        //First input parameter is search bas, it can be "CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"
        //Second Attribute can be uid=username
        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("DC=domain,DC=com", "sAMAccountName="
                + "username", constraints);
        if (answer.hasMore()) {
            Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            System.out.println("distinguishedName "+ attrs.get("distinguishedName"));
            System.out.println("givenname "+ attrs.get("givenname"));
            System.out.println("sn "+ attrs.get("sn"));
            System.out.println("mail "+ attrs.get("mail"));
            System.out.println("telephonenumber "+ attrs.get("telephonenumber"));
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Invalid User");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;
}

}
```